# Installing libraries for every project in Pycharm

Tags: python

I am using latest version of Pycharm  community edition for my Python IDE,  when I will install all necessary libraries for  one project, I need to reinstall it for other projects because I can't import those libraries.

How can I fix this one? Should I install every time? Maybe there is some command by which I can install during program's running time? I mean in shell? I think I should update somehow path, I was searching a lot in internet, but unfortunately could not find anything relevant for this issue, or maybe I  can't guess solution.

Comment: You mean how to use cached packages installed previously? Maybe you should use `pip install` but not the built-in package manager in PyCharm.

Comment: i know this, but  should i install every time?

Comment: Maybe you should set the interpreter environment that contains the packages you installed.

Answer (score 2):

To fix your issue, I suggest you should create a `Virtualenv Environment` and make it available for all projects:

`File`>>`Settings`

`Project`>>`Project Interpreter` >>>>>`Add`

[image]

`New environment`/`Existing Environment` >> [x]Inherit global site-packages 
[x] Make available to all projects >> `[OK]`

[image]

Then install your modules/libs in the `Project Interpreter` box with the symbol `+`

[image]

Whenever you change the project, just pick that `venv` in `Project Interpreter` and use as normal

Comment: but it does not give me possibility to click ok

Comment: yes i know, but it does not gives me  possibility to select ok, should i install  all packages first?

Comment: @datodatuashvili, Your `location` must be an empty directory, and you need to choose `Base Interpreter`, it should be a possibility for the OK button

Comment: and then i have  to   create projects in this empty directory?

Comment: No need, just choose that installed folder as the current `Python Interpreter`

Comment: so that means,  i have to create some  empty directory, install   all necessary package, and  whenever  i  will create  some project, i should include  this  directory as  python interpreter right?

Comment: @datodatuashvili, just take a look at my edit, I create `venv37`, then I use it for `dumps` project, if you change to `other` project, just choose `venv37` as default. That's all!

Comment: ok i have created on my flash  empty directory, i have created project and  try to do  everything  as you said, but no  sucess

Comment: @datodatuashvili I think you should capture your screen what you have tried and your expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195498/discussion-between-le-t-thanh-and-dato-datuashvili).

Comment: yes i have done  now everything, i have created  my virtual environment  and  i have   listed all necessary packages,  can i create my projects inside  this environment?

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Settings. Then from left side go to Project > Project Interpreter. Now, from the Project Interpreter dropdown, you can select your desired environment.

Comment: sorry how ?  i  go to project interpreter, what  i should  do  now?

Comment: Now, select from dropdown, an already created environment, then click Apply button at bottom-right. Now, all the dependencies in the selected environment'll be used for your current project.

Comment: If you already create an environment, it'll appear in dropdown. If not, then when creating an environment check `Make available to all projects`

Comment: no , i think nobody understood correctly my issue, there is no possibility to include all features  you are  telling me

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line to install your packages. This will be easier to import since all packages are installed as global packages but its not recommended because it may cause conflicts between packages.

Then every time you start a new project you just inherit from global package.