# Missing Flask after creating new project

Tags: python, pycharm

.
I downloaded and installed the Flask packages for Pycharm and it worked well on my first Project. But now I want to create a new one, but i cant import Flask anymore. Do I have to install it again and again? Cant I install once on my computer and use it for every project? I am using a virtual environment from Pycharm if that is important.

Comment: Yes, you have to download all requirements for every virtual environment. That's the point, they are completely separate environments

Comment: A new project creates a new virtual environment on Pycharm. You either pip install the packages again or use the same environment created before.

Comment: Ah thanks. But i dont have to download it anymore right? I just have to install it in my new project? Otherwise wouldnt that be very storage waste?

Comment: You can point to the previous `venv`, I don't think you need to re-install again.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer. I hope it helpful for you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749453/installing-libraries-for-every-project-in-pycharm/56750018#56750018

Comment: I looked at the answer. But is there any disadvantage if I use for all projects one Virtual env? Or should I create one for each project?

Comment: Ok sorry i found an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install flask for your local python interpreter via

```
pip install flask
```

Then, when creating your virtual environment you can do:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV
```

source: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

This will copy all installed packages to your new virtual environment.

Keep in mind that is not recommended, as it potentially pollutes your new environment with packages you won't need.

Otherwise, you can download the flask whl file and just install flask locally in your venv.

https://pypi.org/project/Flask/#files

Adjust to Python2/Python3 according to your needs.